# Return nothing if cell contains a character, value from other cell otherwise

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a quote number (a string) in cell I2. If it contains `Q`, I would like M2 to be blank. If it does not contain a `Q`, it should contain the quote number in I2. How can I do this with a formula?

The `Q` will always be the first letter, if this helps.

Comment: Oh yes sir,  straight away sir,  borrow my daughter sir?

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I am struggling with If formulas in excel I have a quote number in cell I2 Q12211 and need to write a formula in the next cell to return as blank if it contains the letter Q and if it does not (for example 12211) then to copy the quote number 12211

Comment: If its always the first character on the left, then it's a simple if function with a nested left.

Answer (score 2):

I found a quite easy solution for you that works. Paste the following in M2:

=IF(LEFT(I2;1)="Q";"";I2)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a solution that isn't always with Q as the first character, or it needs to be case insensitive:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Q",$I2)),"",$I2)
```

[image]